# Responsive headers image repeating on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

So on smaller screens, my current headers I have managed to get down to the size I want using the @media css styling for responsive.  But as the image in my headers is a background image, it repeats when I shrink it down.  I tried switching it to cover, but the image switches back to being full size, so only shows a small snippet of the image instead.. Here is the code I am looking at;

Page - http://outsidetheline.co.uk/01.html
(Focusing on the top image header container)

HTML:

```
<section class="meta-wrapper parallax" style="background-image: url('content/single_blog_bg.png');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20">
    <div id="page_header" class="mini-padding">
        <div class="container-fluid">


        </div>
    </div><!-- end page_header -->
</section><!-- end section -->
```

CSS;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.parallax {
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
#page_header .container-fluid {
    padding: 20rem 0 0;
}
```

The background image css is coming from element-style.
I tried a few things, such as margin:auto, cover rather than contain etc but it results in the image showing huge rather than nicely fitted.

Answer (score 4):

Use `background-repeat: no-repeat`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.parallax {
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;  
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect, this worked, so adding no repeat and removing the background-position fixed this.

So when using no-repeat I need to omit position? as with that, it seems to vanish.  I guess these two conflict.

Thanks loads!

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```css
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: This makes the image vanish oddly